# url to export value from a specific cell in a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

is there a possibility to get the value of a specific cell in a google sheet via a url? (as text/xml string whatever).
I need a calculated value from a cell on a other plattform. preferably just with a GET via a url.

thanks in advance for a tip.

Answer (score 0):

This has been implemented a couple of years ago in Google Sheets:

****Link to: A single cell in a sheet****

1. Click on the spreadsheet cell to be referenced. For example, cell
   C7.
2. Open the contextual menu (using secondary click: right-click,
   ctrl-click, etc.).
3. Scroll down the menu and click on the "Get link to this cell" item.
   The message "The link has been copied to the clipboard" will be
   shown.
4. Paste the link's URL from the clipboard anywhere it's needed. It
   will be similar to:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<file-id>#gid=<sheet-id>&range=<cell>`

Some things to notice about the arguments contained in the fragment identifier of this URL:

`gid`= – This is the ID of a sheet in the spreadsheet. New spreadsheets have one sheet with the ID 0. The ID of the currently visible sheet is usually shown in the browser's URL bar.

`range`= – This is the address of the referenced cell, in "A1 format" (column letter and cell number).

The contextual menu seems to be the only way in the GS UI to get cell URLs. There aren't any other menu items that do this.

Reference:

[Link to a cell in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44473/link-to-a-cell-in-a-google-sheets-via-url)

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i know, but wasnt searching exctly for. Because with this (doing a http get to this url) is parsing the complete html file to find your cell. thats whats i tried to avoid.
But i seesm, there isnt a possibiliy to do a url to a single cell, without api stuff from google. 
so it seems i have to parse the html data from the complete sheet.